# VBA Import Data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem and I think it's complicated. It's regarding importing data/information from a another Excel file and the data/information needed is on 2 sheets.

The code is working but not the way It should be it doesn't seem to import the data and down below it will explain what we cannot do in it, ("me and my friend that are working in this project that was demand by our company don't know almost nothing about this category VBA and we are just researching info about this but get always stuck").

We need to extract from the file (the link is in the description), and the file is created every week(semana) so somehow it needs to extract the newest every week.

Down below there's the Excel file that is responsible for the extraction of the data for security reason we deleted most of the information on it and changed names.

[Workbook with the Macro - Used for importing](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00945992112161453003) The sheet is the number 2 and also It's called Dev.Pag the macro is associated to the button "IMPORT DATA" in the same file.

[Source Workbook - Contains the data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=81304389957905363999) This is where it gets the values(exports) from once again the name and some data was erased because It might compromise the company.

If there's anything I can edited or change please tell me. Thanks in advance for any reply.

Also will post the code down below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Path As String, Lstrw As Long
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWb As Workbook

    'Change this to your company workbook path
    Path = "C:\Users\DZPH8SH\Desktop\Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls"    
    Workbooks.Open (Path)

    'Change "Source" to the name of your company workbook
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks("Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls")        

    'Part that needs some adjustments in down below
    'This part is working good but probably some error in the data
    'transferance may be intrefering with the integridty

    'change the file address
    Set TargetWb = Workbooks("Master_Atual_2015.xlsm") 
    Lstrw = SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    With SourceWb.Sheets(1)
        .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & _
            Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy _
            Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets(1).Range("A3")
    End With

    SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you going to delete the duplicated record? if you did so, maybe you can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904786/removing-duplicate-rows-after-checking-all-columns/30905945#30905945) . So far what i could understand was you are facing the difficulty in removing duplicate row.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I received information from my company that the duplication isn't problem due to the fact that the rows may seem the same but there's light changes in most of them, and even if they are duplicated I can solved it with your reference. But if you downloaded the files you would see the  problem with the import. The code seems fine but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty hard to understand your code for several reasons:

- You just reference the sheets by index. Thus they are hard to find. Better reference them by name
- you reference ranges only by addresses, it would be better to define named ranges

Another point to make it more readable/ debuggable, set the union to an own range object to be able to watch the content and be sure that this is what you want to have.

```
With SourceWb.Sheets(1)
    Set objTargetRange = .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw))
    objTargetRange.Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets(1).Range("A3")
End With
```

When printing out the objTargetRange's addresses it looks like this (You can do that by simply pressing ctrl+g and writing ?objTargetRange.Address)

$D$2:$D$9;$F$2:$F$9;$I$2:$I$9;$M$2:$M$9

So you selected four columns, each of them has 8 cells. When adding this to A3, it will be added side by side, it doesn't have any offset.

So cells A3-D10 will be overwritten by your data, *the code works*. It was not visible that it does that, because comparing state before and state after was pretty complicated. You can make visible, that the changes actually happen by just

- temporary removing your actual data from the sheet
- temporary adding some empty rows

Comment: Still gives me no data import, it seems that everything stays the same, It opens for a second the file that needs to be imported, but nothing happens no data transfer.

Comment: Did you try out to remove the cell content in the target cells to determine if the copy worked or not? Did you try to change the data to be imported to be quite different to check if data will be copied? 
I just tried it out again and it does copy the data from sheet 1 called  "Status 4XX" in workbook "Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls" to sheet "ÄA" which is sheet 1 of "Master_Atual_2015.xlsm"

Comment: The information, can't be mixed up the other sheets except the Dev.Pag(sheet2) is the only one that can receive that information, this due to the information that the other sheets receive. And the Dev.Pag(sheet2) in the columns that are going to receive the data, they are empty and still nothing transfers.

Comment: You are mixing up the sheet names and indexes. Please double check them. It does work like described above.

Comment: I just undestood the huge mistake I was doing. To change to sheet2 it's on "Targetwb.sheets(2)" and "SourceWb.Sheets(2)" right? the data would always go to sheet1...

Comment: Just use it like so: SourceWb.Sheets("Status 4XX") then you cannot mix up names and order of the worksheets. Please mark as answer when it is correct.