# Removing duplicate rows after checking all columns

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have written the below macro to remove duplicate rows after checking all columns. I thought it was working correctly, based on the logic, but the output is not correct, and a few of the rows that should be showing up are being deleted. Can anyone help me with that?

Before this macro is run, i have another macro to sort the data by a few columns to ensure that similar rows are grouped together, so maybe the macro can take that into account, and check only the row above it instead of checking all the rows? Greatly appreciate any help!

```
Sub Delete_Repeated_Rows()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ColumnCounter As Integer

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows

'Using ColumnCounter to hold total number of cells that match. If all of them match, delete row'

 For r = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    ColumnCounter = 0
    For Col = Rng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1 'Loop through columns and find matches'
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(Col), Rng.Cells(r, Col)) > 1 Then
            ColumnCounter = ColumnCounter + 1
        End If
    Next Col

    If ColumnCounter = Rng.Columns.Count Then
        Rng.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Use `Range(TheRange).RemoveDuplicates`. One line of code.

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted a no-code answer to a code question. If you want no code, please say so in your question. But when you post code and ask for improvements, it's really not easy to understand why you would go for a "click-click-click" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the duplicate you can just click the "Remove duplicate" button at Data Ribbon > Data Tools.
[image]

Following is the demo:
I have the data like this in the worksheet:
[image]

 I would like to have unique data at column A
click the "Remove duplicate" button and following screen prompted out and i uncheck columnB
[image]

Click the OK button and there is a notification box telling me that 2 duplicated value been remove and 5 unique value were found as following screen:

[image]

The following is the end result:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

use the built-in RemoveDuplicates command. It will be a lot faster than looping through rows. The only trick in the box is passing the array for the columns parameter.

```
Sub DeDupe()
    Dim intArray As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    With rng
        ReDim intArray(0 To .Columns.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(intArray)
            intArray(i) = i + 1
        Next i
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(intArray), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```